# FIFO construction workers?

Tags: phrase-request

> The construction of the plant will begin with site work, completion of paperwork necessary for the construction of site access roads, and with the construction of living quarters for the **FIFO construction workers**.

I need an expression for "construction workers who will be employed at the site on the fly-in fly-out (FIFO) basis". As I understand, the majority of workers will be employed in in this fashion. But searching for "FIFO construction workers" brings little hits at Google.

What could be a more appropriate expression? A "FIFO construction worker" looks like "a worker who will construct FIFO", an unfelicitious combination. Could it be

> .. quarters for the "fly-in, fly-out" construction workers

Comment: FIFO is a specific type of worker in itself and, if that's what they are, then that's how you should describe them in my opinion.

Comment: Workers who are flown in and out. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22workers%20flown%20in%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: When I see "FIFO", I think of the accounting term "first in, first out".  Because the accounting meaning is relevant in a construction context, I think it is a bad idea to abbreviate "fly-in, fly-out" to FIFO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an acronym, and are concerned that your readers may not be familiar with it (or you are inventing it for the first time), the usual method is to define it on first use.  After that you can use it without further explanation.

> The construction of the plant will begin with site work, completion of paperwork necessary for the construction of site access roads, and with the construction of living quarters for the fly-in-fly-out (FIFO) construction workers.  We anticipate needing to hire at least 2000 FIFO workers...

As Jasper commented, FIFO is commonly used in some fields to mean "first-in-first-out", so there may be a risk of confusion.  You might consider whether some other term would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Other than TRomano's suggestion, you may be able to use **temporary workers**, if that accurately describes this situation (from my understanding of it).